# Speed in a medium

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light, cherenkov-radiation

Let's say, that there is medium, where the speed of light is $10^8 \, \rm m/s$. So in that medium if there exists a particle that is moving through without any hindrance what would be the speed limit of that particle would it $3 \cdot 10^8 \, \rm m/s$ or $10^8 \, \rm m/s$? Since in vacuum the speed limit is equal to the speed of light that is $3 \cdot 10^8 \, \rm m/s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed limit is $3 \times 10^8 m/s$. It's possible to be faster than light in a medium. Notably, you'll get [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) in this case.